# Error using QnAMaker sample with QnAMakerDialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I have been trying to create a constructor of class use Microsoft Cognitive and AI toolkit with QnAMaker API, in order to create a simplistic chat bot.

While my normal qnaMakerAi chat bot works fine, there is an issue while I was trying to enhance it's feature and include the Constructor.
and while running the code in emulator I'm getting below error:

message: Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.
POST:500 directline.postActivity

The issue I'm having is:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Please check and suggest.

Based on the user comments, here is the code for RootDialog -
`

namespace Microsoft.Bot.Sample.QnABot
{

```
 [Serializable]
public class RootDialog : QnAMakerDialog        //IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        /* Wait until the first message is received from the conversation and call MessageReceviedAsync 
        *  to process that message. */
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public RootDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnASubscriptionKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"], "Sorry, I couldn't find an answer for that")))
    {
    }
    protected override async Task RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result)
    {
    }
    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        /* When MessageReceivedAsync is called, it's passed an IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>. To get the message,
         *  await the result. */
        var message = await result;
       // var qnaAuthKey = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAAuthKey");
            var qnaAuthKey = GetSetting("QnAAuthKey");
        // var qnaKBId = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAKnowledgebaseId");
        // var endpointHostName = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAEndpointHostName");
        var qnaKBId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"];
         var endpointHostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAEndpointHostName"];

        // QnA Subscription Key and KnowledgeBase Id null verification
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qnaAuthKey) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(qnaKBId))
        {
            // Forward to the appropriate Dialog based on whether the endpoint hostname is present
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endpointHostName))
                await context.Forward(new BasicQnAMakerPreviewDialog(), AfterAnswerAsync, message, CancellationToken.None);
            else
                await context.Forward(new BasicQnAMakerDialog(), AfterAnswerAsync, message, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Please set QnAKnowledgebaseId, QnAAuthKey and QnAEndpointHostName (if applicable) in App Settings. Learn how to get them at https://aka.ms/qnaabssetup.");
        }

    }

    private async Task AfterAnswerAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        // wait for the next user message
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public static string GetSetting(string key)
    {
        var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && key == "QnAAuthKey")
        {
            value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnASubscriptionKey"]; // QnASubscriptionKey for backward compatibility with QnAMaker (Preview)
        }
        return value;
    }
}

// Dialog for QnAMaker Preview service
[Serializable]
public class BasicQnAMakerPreviewDialog : QnAMakerDialog
{
    // Go to https://qnamaker.ai and feed data, train & publish your QnA Knowledgebase.
    // Parameters to QnAMakerService are:
    // Required: subscriptionKey, knowledgebaseId, 
    // Optional: defaultMessage, scoreThreshold[Range 0.0 – 1.0]
    public BasicQnAMakerPreviewDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(RootDialog.GetSetting("QnAAuthKey"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"], "No good match in FAQ.", 0.5)))
    { }
}

// Dialog for QnAMaker GA service
[Serializable]
public class BasicQnAMakerDialog : QnAMakerDialog
{
    // Go to https://qnamaker.ai and feed data, train & publish your QnA Knowledgebase.
    // Parameters to QnAMakerService are:
    // Required: qnaAuthKey, knowledgebaseId, endpointHostName
    // Optional: defaultMessage, scoreThreshold[Range 0.0 – 1.0]
    public BasicQnAMakerDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(RootDialog.GetSetting("QnAAuthKey"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"], "No good match in FAQ.", 0.5, 1, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAEndpointHostName"])))
    { }

}}
```

`

For RootDialog -

Comment: This RootDialog is not a valid implementation.  QnAMakerDialog's MessageReceivedAsync is not virtual, and cannot be overridden.  (Same with .StartAsync): https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/CSharp/Library/QnAMaker/QnAMaker/QnAMakerDialog.cs#L50

Answer (score 1):

> The issue I'm having is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Based on the code that you provided, I can reproduce the issue. It seems that you create Bot service with **Question and Answer(c#)** template and download the source code from Azure portal, and then you modify the code to make the RootDialog inherit `QnAMakerDialog` class. As Eric Dahlvang mentioned in comment, if you check the definition of `QnAMakerDialog`, you will find the implementation of your RootDialog is invalid.

Besides, based on my test, if you use **QnAAuthKey** and **QnAKnowledgebaseId** of *GA QnAMaker service* to initate your QnAMakerDialog, but not provide **QnAEndpointHostName**, the exception will be thorwn.

[image]

***Note:*** For more information about GA QnAMaker service, you can refer to [this blog](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/05/07/announcing-general-availability-of-qnamaker/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand where exactly you are getting the error.

Just for a suggestion you may try like this too

```
 using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.CognitiveServices.QnAMaker;
    namespace Test.Qna
    {
        [Serializable]
        [QnAMaker(authKey: "AuthKey", knowledgebaseId: "KnowledgebaseId", defaultMessage: "please rephrase, I could not understand.", scoreThreshold: 0.5, top: 1, endpointHostName: "https://yourAccount.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker")]
        public class QnADialog : QnAMakerDialog
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.its working fine after keeping the line below serializable in the above code.

Comment: Welcome bro .. @AbhishekKumar

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating any objects out side of methods, try to create the object inside the method. for example

```
class1 myclass1 = new class1();

public string void MyMethod()
{

}

//above line might be an error.

//do it as



public string void MyMethod()
{
class1 myclass1 = new class1();
}
```